# Reserved words in Java

Tags: java

`goto` is a reserved word in `Java`.

Is it true?

Why so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `goto` is a reserved word in Java.

From the [Sun Docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html):

> The keywords **const** and **goto** are reserved, even though they are not currently used.

Comment: is it to introduce them after sometime?

Comment: Yes, it could be introduced later on if ever the need arises.

Comment: @abson: the motivation to reserve those specific words was that they're used in C++. I'm pretty sure there neve were concrete plans to use them in Java, though. But the possibility is there.